# Running minicom from a bash script for X amount of time (and getting the output)

Tags: shell-script, scripting, minicom

I'm trying to write a script that involves repeatedly calling minicom, letting it run for 60 seconds, getting the output, then killing the job nad moving on to the next directory it runs minicom.
So to do that I'm using the line `timeout 120s minicom` in a script.

However, this doesn't print any of the minicom output to the terminal and when it finishes it kills the script entirely.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

`minicom` documents an option to capture output:

```
   -C, --capturefile=FILE
        filename.  Open capture file at startup.
...
   L    Turn  Capture  file  on  off. If turned on, all output sent to the
        screen will be captured in the file too.
```

Otherwise, you could run `minicom` under something like [Expect](https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/index) and have `expect` capture the output sent to the pty, and timeout the program [after](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/after.html) some number of milliseconds have passed.